Cannot access the IMS cloned from Github
https://github.com/AsjadIqbal/InventoryManagementSystem 
This is the link for the github repository where I cloned the project from. I did everything thats told in the readme file to run the project. I have setup my MySQL credentials userrname: root and password: admin.
I setup these credentials in the DBCredentials as mentioned in the readme file but for some reason when I run the program and try to enter the credentials, it tells me its incorrect.
Additionally I get this error:
PS C:\Users\Dell\OneDrive\Desktop\IMS\InventoryManagementSystem\dist> java -jar InventoryManagement.jar
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:833)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:453)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:246)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:198)
        at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:683)
        at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:230)
        at com.inventory.Database.ConnectionFactory.<init>(ConnectionFactory.java:50)
        at com.inventory.UI.LoginPage.loginButtonActionPerformed(LoginPage.java:167)
        at com.inventory.UI.LoginPage$1.actionPerformed(LoginPage.java:79)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1972)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2314)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:407)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:279)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6621)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3398)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6386)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2266)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4996)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2324)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4828)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4948)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4575)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4516)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2310)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2780)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4828)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:775)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:720)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:714)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:400)
        at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
        at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:98)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:747)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:400)
        at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:744)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.sql.Statement.executeQuery(String)" because "this.statement" is null
        at com.inventory.Database.ConnectionFactory.checkLogin(ConnectionFactory.java:79)
        at com.inventory.UI.LoginPage.loginButtonActionPerformed(LoginPage.java:167)
        at com.inventory.UI.LoginPage$1.actionPerformed(LoginPage.java:79)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1972)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2314)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:407)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:279)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6621)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3398)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6386)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2266)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4996)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2324)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4828)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4948)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4575)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4516)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2310)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2780)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4828)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:775)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:720)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:714)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:400)
        at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
        at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:98)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:747)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:400)
        at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:744)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)

To solve the issue I checked if my sql server was running correctly and yes it was. Also I checked for the connection string in the ConnectionFactory.java and yes the sql server port in my case is 3306 is there and also the db schema is named correct i.e. inventory.
Below is the string, which is actually correct
static final String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/inventory"; // Ensure this matches your setup

Does this answer your question? Access Denied for User 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) - No Privileges?

I did everything thats told in the readme file to run the project. What did it tell you about configuring your DB? In point of fact you should never be logging in as a user called 'root'. In fact, 'root' shouldn't even be allowed to log in at all. The proper password for root in MySql.User should be invalid and root can't log in

Set up the user properly in the db and you should still be able to log in as 'root' in the gui

I have setup my MySQL credentials userrname: root and password: admin. Did you setup MySQL? And does mysql -u root --password admin inventory work from the command line? Because if the mysql command line client can't connect, Java can't either.

I think it connected when I did mysql -u root --password admin inventory, because it displayed several things such as : C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin>mysql -u root --password admin inventory
mysql  Ver 8.0.37 for Win64 on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)
Copyright (c) 2000, 2024, Oracle and/or its affiliates.
Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.
BUT I still couldnt get access in the program itself.

Also the problem seems to be on the frontend rather than the sql workbench.

afaicr the password is not 'admin' but 'root'

@goose But I have put up my sql workbench password as admin, and user name root.
